# Battlescreen not working in Battlefield 4

Tags: battlefield-4

I have multiple monitors, and I'd like to run Battlescreen on one of them. The issue is that the browser just displays a page that says "Loading Battlescreen" with the blinky cursor, but nothing happens after that.

I'm using Chrome but also tried IE with the exact same results. OS is Win8 x64.

I have added firewall exceptions for Battlefield, Battlefield (x64) and the ESN Sonar Host App.

I haven't yet tried if it'd work on a tablet; I assume it would but I'd much rather have the map shown on a big desktop monitor rather than a tiny portable screen.

Comment: It doesn't work for me either. It worked on the day of release but not since that day. It says connection problem for me, though. It might just be disabled for now.

Comment: It might say "connection problem" or something different but unhelpful if Battlescreen is not started at the "right time". If I alt-tab out of the game when I'm on the map and try to load Battlescreen, that's when the loading message is shown, but sadly, it never actually loads anything.

Comment: Some of my friends also have problems with battlescreen. Seems like there are some bugs that need fixing.

Comment: Try with Firefox, i played couple games with Battlescreen on second monitor.

Comment: Same thing with Firefox unfortunately.

Comment: Opera did not work for me. FF and Chrome worked. Only difference: Cookies are disabled in Opera in general, only allowed for BattleLog (which works in general!). Cannot test if this can be the issue - but maybe it is worth a try - and you know probably if you have a similar restrictive setting in your browsers.

Comment: Tried enabling 3rd party cookies, made no difference. Thx for the tip though.

Comment: Have you installed the plugin from DICE for the browser you are using?

Comment: Yeah, that was the first thing I checked.

Comment: Are you on a hardcore server, or one with minimap off?

Comment: @harbichidian: Battlescreen works in hardcore and normal. Or it has been.

Comment: @prolink007 Battlescreen has *never* worked on Hardcore servers, for me. It just stays on the loading screen the whole round.

Comment: It started working for me consistently

Comment: With all the issues I've had with BF4 the thing that stopped the issues was changing my DNS servers.  If you are seeing "connection problem" this might do the trick! (I used 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4)

Comment: changing DNS server made it work for me in chrome. still doesnt work in firefox, stuck in "loading screen".

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is occurring with a lot of people. [EA has recently provided a help link for Battlescreen connectivity issues.](http://help.ea.com/en/article/how-to-troubleshoot-connectivity-issues/) It appears that Battlescreen uses some ports that may be completely blocked incoming/outgoing by your firewall or antivirus, but some of the suggestions they give lead me to believe that it was poorly designed from a connectivity perspective.

Under "Advanced", they provide useful information like flushing the DNS cache, UO trace, plugging directly into the modem, etc.

However it would be useful in providing in answer if you could tell us if you have access to Battlescreen on your computer when you are not running Battlefield 4 alongside.